# How to display database table on Wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, wampserver

I created a database name:'upsdatabase',table name:'upstable' in phpmyadmin using wamp server. I have four columns. I created upsTest.php for display the table on browser.It's displaying correctly but **I want to display on wordpress page**
how to display Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will not identify the table till the time it has the same table_prefix as used in wp-config.php

so open the wp-config file , check $table_prefix and prepend your current table with that.

after that you may use $wpdb and then your query for e.g:-

```
// 1st Method - Declaring $wpdb as global and using it to execute an SQL query statement that returns a PHP object

global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = 1', OBJECT );

// 2nd Method - Utilizing the $GLOBALS superglobal. Does not require global keyword ( but may not be best practice )

$results = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = 1', OBJECT );
```

check this link for more info on $wpdb

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: then  How to display?